# EasyMock - mock object returned from new Object

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Is it possible, with a capture for example, to return a mock when a method is called from a new object?

To make it more concrete:

```
SecurityInterface client = new SecurityInterface();
port = client.getSecurityPortType(); --> I want to mock this.
```

easymock version: 3.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you also use [Powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) your test code can intercept the calls to `new` and return a mock instead.  So you can return a mock for `new SecurityInterface()` and then mock its getter

Powermock is compatible with Easymock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( MyClass.class )
public class TestMyClass {

@Test
public void foo() throws Exception {
   SecurityInterface mock = createMock(SecurityInterface.class);

    //intercepts call to new SecurityInterface and returns a mock instead
    expectNew(SecurityInterface.class).andReturn(mock);
    ...
    replay(mock, SecurityInterface.class);
    ...
    verify(mock, SecurityInterface.class);
}

}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't think of powermock. Good suggestion!

Comment: This is a good approach but the issue is in coder coverage, if we are using PowerMock then EclEmma eclipse plugin is not providing code coverage, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

No - this is exactly the sort of static coupling that you need to design out of your classes in order to make them testable.

You would need to provide the `SecurityInterface` via a supplier or a factory which you inject: you can then inject an instance which invokes `new` in your production code, and an instance which returns a mock in your test code.

```
class MyClass {
  void doSomething(SecurityInterfaceSupplier supplier) {
    Object port = supplier.get().getSecurityPortType();
  }
}

interface SecurityInterfaceSupplier {
  SecurityInterface get();
}

class ProductionSecurityInterfaceSupplier implements SecurityInterfaceSupplier {
  @Override public SecurityInterface get() { return new SecurityInterface(); }
}

class TestingSecurityInterfaceSupplier implements SecurityInterfaceSupplier {
  @Override public SecurityInterface get() { return mockSecurityInterface; }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm unable to work in a CDI / EJB context and I can't inject anything. Otherwise I would haven been able to do this indeed. Forgot to mention this..