# is there any way to test/mock a File input using junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am trying to test the following code without using a real xls file...

```
File file = new File("file.xls");
final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

My problem is that I cannot create an instance of File, and I dont know how to simulate I am creating a new file and how to mock what to expect.

Is there any way to do this using junit?

Thanks

Comment: **My problem is that I cannot create an instance of File**  - why?

Comment: there is no way to make a new File(); and I dont know which method implements to be able to create an instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple different ways.

You can use something like Powermock to intercept the call to new. See this other answer where  I explain how to do that in detail [EasyMock - mock object returned from new Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241635/easymock-mock-object-returned-from-new-object/33244877#33244877)

Do you actually want the bytes from the excel file or an "excel object"?  It might be worth refactoring to pass around a `Workbook` object or whatever you are using to parse the excel downstream and then use dependency injection.  Your test can then inject a mock Workbook object instead of a real file.